# Directive loads before attributes are set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that looks like the following

```
   app.directive("responses", function ()
   {
    return {
        templateUrl: "/templates/responses.html",

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl)
        {
            var type = attrs.type;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the directive in the html markup. The `type` attribute is set by the controller. It is the result from a `$http` call

```
<div responses type="{{Data.Type}}"></div>
```

However, when the directive goes to retrieve this attribute, it has not been set yet by the parent controller. So when the directive loads, the `type` is ultimately set to nothing. I suppose I could resolve with a `setInterval()` but that doesn't seem the best way. Any thoughts?

Here is the simplified controller

```
   controllers.AppCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, $http)
   {
         $scope.Data ={
               Type = ""
         }

          $http.get("http://restfulURI/3").success(function (result)
          {
                $scope.Data.Type = result.Type;
          }
    }
```

Comment: is the data coming from outside the angular scope?

Comment: Yes. It results from a $http call

Comment: your view might not be updating because when the data is changed, or rather loaded, it is not resulting in a $digest cycle to run. Can you add the controller code where the data is being loaded?

Comment: ok. added the controller code

Comment: try changing the .success to .then and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @prawn how about trying my plunker below http://plnkr.co/edit/ibHlcyrv3sxFnJylrX47?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `scope.$watch` instead:

```
app.directive("responses",function(){
    return {
       templateUrl: "/templates/responses.html",

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl){
          scope.$watch(attrs.type,function(newvalue,oldvalue){
             //on attribute value changes
          });
        }
    }
});
```

`$watch` will add a listener event on attribute property and once it changes it will trigger the event on  your directive.

Here is [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibHlcyrv3sxFnJylrX47?p=preview)

Comment: I've tried adding the $watch like in your example, but the attrs.type and oldvalue and newvalue are all undefined. Do I need to define the scope somehow on the directive itself?

Comment: first time I guess it is undefine but if you set Data.Type to something in your controller it should reflect that

Comment: Ah! Examined your plunker demo. It turns out the root of the problem was having the double curly braces around around the attribute "type". Changing it to type="Data.Type" resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a watcher if you want to launch some special action when the attribute changes 
also if you are not using isolated scopes there is not much point in watching an attribute since you have access to the controllers scope anyways you can just watch for Data.Type  changing. in order to provide a better solution we would need to know more about the final application and what do you want to achieve.